# Jimmy got a 38.5% (± 0.05%) on his math test. How many questions did the test have at a minimum?

Tags: rational-numbers, percentages

The answer is not "200 questions", though it would be if he got a score of **exactly** 38.5%. The fact that anything that rounds to the nearest decimal is allowed complicates things.

I know the answer, but can it be solved without brute force?

Comment: 39 I think. But in theory there could be as few or as many questions as you want.

Comment: You wouldn't be able to get 38.5% (± 0.05%) on a two-question test (for example), assuming that each question has equal weight (which I believe is a reasonable premise here).

Comment: I believe that a couple of hypotheses are missing here: one is that all questions carry the same points (as you say yourself), and the other one is that either awards the full amount of points or none at all. These are probably reasonable assumptions for, say, multiple choice tests, but fairly uncommon for tests with open questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Continued fractions.
$$0.385 = \frac1{2+\frac1{1+\frac1{1+\frac1{2+\frac1{15}}}}} $$
and
$$ \frac1{2+\frac1{1+\frac1{1+\frac1{2}}}}=\frac5{13}\approx 0.3846$$
so it could have been $13$ questions.

It could not have bneen less because any fraction$\frac ab$ between $\frac38=0.375$ and $\frac25=0.4$ has $b\ge 13$: We have $\frac ab>\frac38$, which implies that the numerator of $\frac ab-\frac38=\frac{8a-3b}{8b}$ is $\ge1$ and on the other hand the numerator of $\frac25-\frac ab=\frac{2b-5a}{5b}$ is also $\ge1$, so that $$b= 5\cdot(8a-3b)+8\cdot(2b-5a)b\ge 5+8=13$$